# Как реализовать загрузку информации с текстового файла?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Написал код, здесь реализовано функцию Join, функция передает информацию в textbox. Мне нужно реализовать загрузку этой информации из textbox в файл(.txt) и выгрузку от туда обратно. Загрузку информации в файл я реализовал, но как загружать информацию из файла в textbox мне не понятно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Ниже предоставил код программы.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"E:\OPI\ОПИ\lab4\lab4\1.txt";

        string[] arr = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text };
        string joined = string.Join(" | ", arr);
        textBox3.Text = joined;

        FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(file);
        stream.Write(textBox3.Text);

        stream.Close();
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Ну так делайте обратное, читаете данные и через `.Split()` разбиваете по вашему символу. Из замечаний - вы не закрываете `*Stream`, используйте `using`, ну а вообще, почему просто не использовать `File.Read..()` и `File.Write...()`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ только начал изучать программирование, пока что не знаю еще тонкостей, спасибо

Comment: Ваша логика не поломается, если юзер в текстбокс вам напишет `какой | то | текст | c | вертикальными | черточками` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вас, то как-то так:

```
    private void SetText()
    {
        string path = @"E:\OPI\ОПИ\lab4\lab4\1.txt";
        string[] values;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

            textBox3.Text = text;

            values = text.Split(" | ");
        }

        textBox1.Text = values[0];
        textBox2.Text = values[1];
    }
```

Comment: Да, именно так, только вот еще нужно и третий textbox загружать в программу. У меня выдает ошибку на этом моменте.

Comment: Хочу добавить, информация с двух textbox передается в третий, под видом info | info. Как мне третий textbox тоже загрузить из файла?

Comment: Добавил пробелы в разделитель

Comment: @xxxzeddd Исправил

Comment: а чего бы не просто `var text = File.ReadAllText(path);` ?

Comment: Не вижу особой разницы, но работа с файлами как со стримами выглядит чуть высокоуровнее и приводит код к единому формату.

Comment: @SmorcIRL странное решение использовать код 10-летней давности и называть его "высокоуровневее", чем чтение файла в один вызов метода. Как раз все наоборот.

Comment: @aepot И правда, глупость написал, под копотом у методов File те же стримы